# Is reading an integer and then declaring array of size correspond to that integer is dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning Data Structures from Schaum's Outlines Data Structures book, and a paragraph says.

> On the other hand, some programming languages allow one to
> read an integer n and then declare an array with n elements; such programming languages
> are said to allocate memory dynamically.

Please answer the commented question in the following program written in c++.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    
    int n;

    std::cin >> n;   // reading at runtime.  step1.

    int *arr1 = new int[n];  // I know it is meant for dynamic allocation.  step2.

    int arr2[n];    // Is this dynamic allocation? As reading input at runtime
                    // and creating the array of size correspond to the input taken in step1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The search term here would be "variable length arrays". I'm looking for a question on StackOverflow that would explain the concept (rather than why it is a bad idea), but I can't find anything... Anyway, they are not a part of C++ standard, some compilers support them as extension.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont May you be a bit more explicit about the meaning of your comment, I know this question is little awkward, But, I was just confused when I saw this in the textbook.

Comment: Anyway, thank you @Yksisarvinen

Comment: The duplicate I propose explains that VLAs are not part of C++, has a link on what they are and explains why ("sometimes") code using them does still compile. Please include the things said in the question into your search for an answer.

Comment: Well, it was an honest question to ask you.  **Is an egg a bird?**  If you can find a definitive, universal answer to my question, then we can answer the question "is this dynamic memory allocation".